# Generate XML output to a fitting format to match my XSLT

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xslt

Hey, I am writing a quiz application with Java Servlets. My quiz data is written into XML files, i.e.: `<quiz><question><ask>...</ask><answer>...</answer>...</question></quiz>`.

I want to display every question and their answers on a single page. For that reason, I cannot simply transform the XML to my XSLT as it would display only the first question or all questions. My guess is, I should load the XML data in order to create my own Java classes, i.e.: class Question, class Quiz, etc and generate from them a XML format which fits my XSLT displaying only one question at a time.

Is this approach the right way and if so, how is this realized?

If not, how is it done probably?

Comment: @BrockenClockwork: It is not clear at all what is your question, please learn to specify a question well: what is the XML document, what is the desired result of the transformation, what are the rules that the transformation must obey.

Comment: A very confusing question. You seem to be suggesting that you have "an XSLT" (meaning, presumably, a stylesheet) which doesn't do the job you want it to do. If that's the case, then the right approach is to change it so it does the right thing.

Comment: XSLT processor doesn't know anything about "pages". That's into the scope of an specific XML vocabulary for specific render media. So, without this data, this is not a real question, and it won't help anybody...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot simply transform the XML to my XSLT as it would display only the first question or all questions.

You are wrong. If you write your XSLT using templates and the correct XPath, a transform could output all of the questions that exist in one XML file, however many.

You can also use XPath to select specific `question` nodes, depending on attribute values (for example).

If you have the following template and use the right XPath to select all questions in an `apply-templates`, this template will be applied to *each* question, not just the first:

```
<xsl:template match="question">

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: All questions? I want to output only specific questions

Comment: @BrokenClockwork - from your question: `I want to display every question and their answers on a single page`. Which is it then?

Comment: @BrokenClockwork - Also, can you explain your selection criteria for which questions to show and which ones not? It is possible that this can all be done with XSLT.

Comment: Sorry, I misphrased my question. What I meant is: I want to display each question on another page. One question per page results for 5 question into 5 pages, which are hopefully realized by only 1 XSL file.

Comment: @Oded: Yes. I identify questions by an attribute id, so I could select them on that criteria. Thanks :)

Comment: @BrokenClockwork - Answer amended, though only slightly... Assuming all questions are collected in one XML file, this isn't difficult to achieve in XSLT.